# GCP Cloud SQL MSSQL DB not accessible after restore from bucket

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I have issue and it seems that cant find solution. I have created Clous SQL instance in GCP and i have restored MS SQL database from the bucket, but I'm unable to access it with any of my users here is the message from the MS Management studio  "The server principal "user" is not able to access the database
"user_db" under the current security context."

There seems to be no way to assignee users to database, can anyone help me how can i assignee or map user to this restored DB ?

Comment: Not sure what your exact problem is, I've never restored a database in cloud sql, but users can easily be managed from the cloud console (assuming your account has sql admin permissions in the project or for that database): https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/sqlserver/create-manage-users.

Comment: My problem is that non of the sql users in sql instane at cloud sql can access the database that i have restored from the bucket, if some of the users create databese from query or management studio or cloud sql user interface they can access it and use it. Even if i create new user he still will not have access to the database that i restored form the bucket.